# Hide child of component on click with duplicate component

Tags: angular

I would like when I click on the first  to have it show me ONLY HIS children , now when I click on either parent it automatically shows me ALL the children

html:

```
<app-menu-section [title]="'Save screenshot'" (click)="updateClickStatus()">
    <app-menu-section [title]="'Button color'" [class]="'menu-button'" *ngIf="clicked"></app-menu-section>
</app-menu-section>

<app-menu-section [title]="'Edit screenshot'" (click)="updateClickStatus()">
    <app-menu-section [title]="'Button color'" [class]="'menu-button'" *ngIf="clicked"></app-menu-section>
    <app-menu-section [title]="'Background color'" [class]="'menu-button'" *ngIf="clicked"></app-menu-section>
</app-menu-section>
```

typescript (of menu-section):

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-menu-container',
    templateUrl: './menu-container.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./menu-container.component.css'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class MenuContainerComponent implements OnInit {
    clicked: boolean = false;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }

    updateClickStatus(): void {
        this.clicked = !this.clicked;
    }

}
```

A component-only variable would be useful

Comment: You can try creating one directive and add the behavior in that.

Comment: I should create declare how many sections (parent) there are, I want it to be all automatic.